# What is the magnitude of a super-nova on the Richter scale?

Tags: supernova, scaling, earthquake

What is the richter scale of a super-nova?

If one could measure compare it to standard earthquakes measured in logarithmic richter scale, what would be the value for a super-nova?

Comment: The [Richter scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_magnitude_scale) has various shortcomings, so it isn't actually used much these days. Instead, other logarithmic scales, like the moment magnitude scale, are used, although the news media tend to use the old Richter name when reporting those numbers. A unit used for supernova energies is the [foe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foe_(unit)), $10^{44}$ joules. An average supernova can release a foe just in radiant energy. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia (and the comment from PM 2Ring) tell me that it's reasonable to assume an energy release from a supernova of about $10^{44}$ joules.  The energy  released by an earthquake is sometimes given as $10^{4.4+1.5M}$ where $M$ is the Richter scale measurement.  This gives $44=4.4+1.5M$ or $M=26.5$.

You might want to modify this a bit depending on exactly how you want to define the "energy release" associated with an earthquake; you can see some discussion about this [here](http://earthalabama.com/energy.html#/).

Comment: That 1 foe is just for the radiant energy, the total energy released by a supernova can be quite a bit more than 1 foe, as I described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/455549/123208).