# Momentum of photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons, photon-emission

We know that photons (light) are massless but they have momentum. Now suppose I am in the space far away from planets/stars that there is no external force exerts on me, if:

1- I turn on a flashlight (torch), would I be pushed in the opposite direction which the flashlight is facing (Newton's third law)?

2- If a star is shedding light on me (its photons hit my body), would I start moving due the impact of the photos?

Comment: See [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes in both cases. In fact there is no need to invoke the concept of photons; electromagnetic radiation consistent with Maxwell's equations carries momentum.

You might care to search online for articles on *photon propulsion* and *solar sails*.

Comment: Note that it takes a *lot* of energy. For light, $E=pc$, so (for example) to give 1 kg an impulse of 1 m/s takes almost 300 megajoules.

Comment: which is why there are many proposals for practical applications but few if any actual implementations.

Comment: @PM2Ring  "lot of energy"   -- everything is relative to what you expect :-) .  A supernova will produce enough photons to accelerate the crap out of your General Products Number 4 Hull.

Comment: @Carl Sure, but if you're that close to a supernova, even the neutrino (& antineutrino) flux will make things "interesting". On the topic of supernova energies, please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/455549/123208 ;)