# Do supernovas vaporize the local space rocks 10 Pluto distances away?

Tags: astrophysics, radiation, estimation, supernova

In a follow-up to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455526/) question,

What would it be like to watch an average space rock / ice comet at 1-20 Pluto distances from a supernova of $10^{44}$ joules?

At what proximity would they become vapor/lava/above $100^\circ C$? How fast would they deflect into space? Would it be like smashing them with a cosmic hammer with a sudden force? Would the force rise over minutes and hours like a rail gun?

$$
E'=\frac{\pi R^2}{4\pi r^2}E\approx 10^{-16}E.
$$
Chiral Anomaly's formula linked above tells me that a melon sized boulder of 8kg at 1ly from the supernova will get $10^{26}$ joules of energy, and $10^{21}$ joules at 3ly.

There's also a lot of matter ejected nearly at *c*, At 10 pluto distances a melon sized rock would take about 1-3kg of that matter at 300AU it's $118kg^{m3}$  ( $6*10^{30}kg$ / $4*10^{22}km^2$ )..

What is mysterious is the thermal energy accrued by the rock, and gamma rays/neutrinos which traverse through it.

I'm wrongly imagining that supernovas throw spheres of millions of local comets outwards like a game of cosmic billiards, including ice comets with DNA life from nearby planets.

Comment: The energy released in various types of [supernovae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) varies by more than a factor of 50, so this question seems underdetermined.

Comment: Hi LifeInTheTrees. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: @Qmechanic, good idea, using Chiral Anomaly's formula, I find that a melon sized rock has higher surface to weight ratio than a star, so at 3 ly away it's hit by 10 million times more energy/kg than the star and would be deflected by 10,000 km/year, at 0.1 light year, that number would be 10km/s at least however it's like moving a rock with a laser? I don't know at what distance from a supernova a rock would be ionized, perhaps 0.01ly, perhaps 3ly.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees what is Chiral Anomaly's formula? reference?

Comment: @Quillo It's on the link at the top of the question, end of the first answer.

Comment: OK, the formula written by the user "Chiral Anomaly" (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/455544/226902), not the physical process known as "chiral anomaly" (that has nothing to do with rocks in space)! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly

Comment: Temperatures of supernova shocks are in the millions of degrees (cf [this LiveScience article](https://www.livescience.com/64651-temperature-in-supernova-heat-shock.html)). Not much chance an ice ball could survive interaction with that.

Comment: Cheers Kyle Kanos the 1987a supernova is an invaluable resource for astronomers and I hadn't yet studied it.

Comment: Relevant:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232199/59023

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical supernova emits an energy of $10^{44}$ joules.
According to [Supernova - Light curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova#Light_curves) a typical supernova explosion
has a duration of $100$ days, i.e. $10^7$ seconds.
This results in a power of
$$P=\frac{10^{44}\text{ J}}{10^7\text{ s}}=10^{37}\text{ W}$$

Let's consider a distance $10$ times the distance to [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto).
$$r=10 \cdot 6 \cdot 10^9\text{ km}=6\cdot 10^{13}\text{ m}$$

At this distance from the supernova you have a radiation intensity
$$I=\frac{P}{4\pi r^2}
=\frac{10^{37}\text{ W}}{4\pi\cdot (6\cdot 10^{13}\text{ m})^2}
= 2\cdot 10^8\text{ W/m}^2$$

We can use the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) ($I=\sigma T^4$) to roughly
calculate the temperature $T$ a body aquires by absorbing this radiation intensity.
$$T=\sqrt[4]\frac{I}{\sigma}
=\sqrt[4]\frac{2\cdot 10^8\text{ W/m}^2}{5.7\cdot 10^{-8}\text{ W/m}^2\text{K}^4}
=8000\text{ K}$$
This temperature is well above the [boiling point of rocks](https://www.google.de/search?q=boiling+point+of+rocks) and [metals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_point#Boiling_point_of_chemical_elements).
So everything will evaporate there.

Comment: That's the total energy, but most of it goes into neutrinos, right?  How much goes into electromagnetic radiation that can be absorbed by an object?